# Points not added to the map plot

Tags: r, r-sp

I need to add some points to the map using simple `points` function. The issue is that points don't add to the map. It's simple command, I follow some tutorial where adding points to the map works this way but not in my case. `Plot` function plots Texas choropleth properly but next line (`points`) doesn't add points to the map at all:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

companies <- read.csv('geoloc_data_comp.csv', header = T, dec = ',', sep = ';')
states <- readOGR('.', 'states')

plot(states[states@data$stat_name == 'texas',])
points(companies$coords.x1, companies$coords.x2, pch = 21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you shoud start to avoid `rgeos`/`rgdal` because they will stop being maintains. See : https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution

`sf` is replacing them:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(spData) #used because I wanted US states
# list of data in spData you have one with US states
data(package = "spData")
```

if you want to read shapefile or other GIS format check `sf::st_read()` (instead of `readOGR()`)

```
# one way with sf
plot(us_states$geometry[us_states$NAME == "Texas"]) 
# if you want do use the sp way  
us_sp <- as(us_states, "Spatial") # convert to sp
plot(us_sp[us_sp@data$NAME == "Texas",])
```

with `sf` you have the geometry in one column (see "geometry") instead of having an R S4 with nested lists (see @data and @polygones).

Before getting some points we need to check in which CRS our data are. If you do not know CRS I like this website : https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/

You also have information in the us_states documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spData/versions/2.0.1/topics/us_states

Then you can use:

```
sp::proj4string(us_sp)
sf::st_crs(us_states)
# This is EPSG 4269 or NAD83
```

If you want to use `points()` they need to be in this coordinates system (**I suspect this explain your trouble** ie different CRS).

You didn't provide data points so I produced some:

```
library(osmdata)
#this will just download node matching the key/value place=city
some_city_in_texas <- osmdata::opq(osmdata::getbb("Texas US"),
                                   nodes_only = TRUE) %>% 
            osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "place", value = "city") %>% 
            osmdata::osmdata_sf() #keep them in sf format 
                                  # osmdata_sp() also exist
```

The class osmdata is a bit complicated but here you just need to know that `some_city_in_texas$osm_points` provide us with points (to test `points()`). Now we can check their CRS:

```
sf::st_crs(some_city_in_texas$osm_points)
```

As you can see we are in an other CRS so we need to transform it. (you will probably need to do it).

```
city_in_texas <- sf::st_transform(some_city_in_texas$osm_points,
                                  4269)
```

`sf` use simple feature standard to store localization and `points()` want two vectors x&y. You should also check that (common cause of error): R use x/y (long/lat) and not lat/long.

Here we convert `city_in_texas` to just coords. (if you need to do the reverse, ie converting data frame with X/Y,  into  an sf object look at `sf::st_as_sf()`)

```
coords_city <- sf::st_coordinates(city_in_texas)
```

Finally this works fine now:

```
plot(us_states$geometry[us_states$NAME == "Texas"]) 
points(coords_city, pch = 21)
```

Good ressources are https://r-spatial.org/ and https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/

Comment: Thank you for very  good explanation!